# Moving files to a subfolder based on partial filename with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

at work I am constantly moving email files (.msg) to certain subfolders based on the number of the file and it takes up a lot of my time so I've been trying to automatize with VBA recently. However, I could only manage (I am a beginner at VBA btw) to create a script to move the files to a folder if the name of the file coincides with the name of the folder. The problem is that the name of the file matches the name of the subfolder only partially. We create a folder for each deal we have and those deals are each identified by a 6 digit number. Then we name all the files pertaining to that specific deal with a numerical sequence.

For example, let's say we have a deal #567567. We create a subfolder called 567567. Then we numerate all files related to that deal as this: 01 - 567567, 02 - 567567, 03 - 567567 and so on. I then move those files to the corresponding folder manually. I was wondering if there was any way to automatize this with VBA considering only a part of the file name matches with the destination folder name. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read through this guide - [ask] and [mre]. Request you to add some code which you have tried so far.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the [`Dir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) function. It would help if you [edit]ed your question with the code you currently have.

Comment: Is the pattern ## - ###### always the first 10 characters of the filename ? If the sub folder does not exist do you want to create it with the macro ?.